# Jenkins SSL GitHub WebHooks

Tags: github, ssl, jenkins, webhooks

I'm trying to integrate Jenkins GitHub webhooks so as to trigger the Jenkins jobs automatically whenever there is a commit made to the respective repos.

Jenkins version : 2.138.1, github : 1.29.2, gitplugin: 3.9.1

Jenkins is running on SSL, running with external url with security. Please note, when ran manually the job is able to ssh and clones the github code.

Under GitHub webhook settings I have configured **https://myjenkins.com/github-webhook/** by selecting "**application/json**" but facing below error

**We couldn’t deliver this payload: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority**

Do we need to add GitHub cert into the **/java/cacerts in Jenkins server? am I missing any other settings?

Can someone suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It's the other way around. GitHub is failing the validate the Certificate you have for Jenkins. If you don't have a proper CA Signed certificate you can try disabling SSL Validations.(Not recommended) Or configure a proper certificate for Jenkins.

[image]

If the URL you provided is the actual one, it seems your certificate is issued to `*.accountservergroup.com` but the hostname you are using is `myjenkins.com`. You need to update the host to something like this `myjenkins.accountservergroup.com`.

[image]

Comment: we have the valid CA singed cert. Any other suggestions

Comment: @kumar take a look at the updated answer.